# SQL - How to Add Value X when Value X does not exist against possible multiple values for each record

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a list a people with the fruit they like to eat, against each person.

For example:-

```
Jack, Apple.
Jack, Banana.
Jack, Orange.
Emma, Apple.
Bob, Melon.
```

I'm wanting to insert a line with the value 'Banana' against each person, that doesn't already this value. I'm sure I'm missing something, as when I use Not In, I am getting the records for Jack, Apple. Which would then add another Banana record when he already has one.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Show the query that you have tried.

Comment: Please tag the exact database

Comment: It is easier for contributors to help you if they knew what you have already tried. Kind of a proof that you did your due diligence to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for SQL Server at least:

```
Declare     @PersonFruit Table 
    (
        Person  varchar(50), 
        Fruit   varchar(50)
    ); 

Insert Into @PersonFruit Values('Jack', 'Apple')  
Insert Into @PersonFruit Values('Jack', 'Banana') 
Insert Into @PersonFruit Values('Jack', 'Orange')
Insert Into @PersonFruit Values('Emma', 'Apple')
Insert Into @PersonFruit Values('Bob', 'Melon') 

-- Insert Banana for persons who didn't already have it 
Insert Into @PersonFruit 
Select  Person, 'Banana'
From    @PersonFruit 
Where   Person Not In 
    (Select Person From @PersonFruit Where Fruit = 'Banana')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table [dbo].SoTablename(
    [FirstColumn] [nvarchar](10),
    [SecondColumn] [nvarchar](10)
)
GO


insert into [dbo].SoTablename values ('Jack', 'apple')
insert into [dbo].SoTablename values ('Jack', 'banana')
insert into [dbo].SoTablename values ('Jack', 'orange')
insert into [dbo].SoTablename values ('Emma', 'apple')
insert into [dbo].SoTablename values ('Bob', 'banana')


Select * From SoTablename
```

[image]

```
;with temp as
    (select
    k.FirstColumn,
    case
        when exists (select * from dbo.SoTablename where FirstColumn = k.FirstColumn and SecondColumn = 'banana')
        then 1
    else
        0
    end as 'ExistsOrNot'
    from
        dbo.SoTablename k
    )
Insert Into dbo.SoTablename
select 
    FirstColumn, 'banana'
from temp
where existsornot = 0


Select * From SoTablename
```

[image]